# In-app billing or Paypal

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I'd like to insert an in-app payement method in my app. What is the best solution for you? But most of all, why? Is there a more convenient or profitable one?

Comment: Unfortunate this was closed.  A nice pro and con answer for paypal vs. google in-app billing would be an excellent asset for new android programmers.  Sometimes I think moderation is a bit over zealous on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be surprised if this gets closed as subjective/open-ended, however...

The 'best' solution depends largely on how often you're billing, how variable amounts are, and what merchant accounts you have set up, etc.

For end-user ease-of-use I'd probably go with the [In-app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html), but you could probably use the new [license manager](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) functionality to support multiple payment channels.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello